# I have a problem with sorting in python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have to write a code that:

1. opens a file
2. read it
3. split it
4. if the words not in NewList i have to add them to it
5. return that list in alphabetical order, but sort() returns me none
   Here's the link to the code thanks guys
   https://github.com/giuamato50/python

```
def sorting():
    newlist=[]
    file='romeo.txt'
    handle=open(file)
    for line in handle:
        words=line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word not in newlist:
                newlist.append(word)
        x=newlist.sort()
    return x
print(sorting())
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question in a formatted code block. It's fine to provide links to longer bits of code, but having the relevant parts in the question ensures that the question and answer remain useful even when the original code is no longer online.

Comment: Post code examples in the question, not as a link. And make it a complete example we can run. Also, include any useful information about what went wrong when you ran it. A github reference may be useful if somebody wants to send you a pull request, but stackoverflow questions should be one-stop shopping without going to external sites.

Comment: Confusingly, `sort(array)` and `array.sort()` don't do the same thing.  The first leaves the list unmodified, but returns a new array with the elements in sorted order.  The latter sorts the elements in place, and returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite `x` on every iteration of the loop, that's not needed. Also, you call `.sort()` on the list, which sorts it in place and returns None, which is what you assign to `x`. Use `sorted()` instead for that syntax.

With that fixed:

```
def sorting():
    newlist=[]
    file='romeo.txt'
    handle=open(file)
    for line in handle:
        words=line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word not in newlist:
                newlist.append(word)
    return sorted(newlist)
print(sorting())
```

There's more ways to improve your code, but this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Program sorts list alphabetically and uses list comprehension for concise and faster code.

Edit: Added .strip() to remove \n in list

Edit 2: Added key=lambda l: l.lower() to sort alphabetically regardless of case

```
def sorting():
    newlist=[]
    file='julia.txt'
    handle=open(file)
    newlist= [line.strip() for line in handle for word in line.split() if word not in newlist] 
    return sorted(newlist, key=lambda l: l.lower())

print(sorting())
```